# Get Response of another javascript function in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two java-script function. In one function i have called another function. Its working fine. But the problem is first function not getting response from second java script. I have requirement if the first function return true then second will execute rest code.

My Code.

```
function NextData() {           
        var lQIndex = $('#hfLastQIndex').val();  
        if (SaveData(lQIndex)) {
            alert('1111111');
            //Rest Code....
        }            
}

function SaveData(QNo) {   
        var flag = false;
         $.ajax({
            url: '/Assessment/Save',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {A:QNo},
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("Test: " + data.result);
                if (data.result == "T")
                    flag = true;                   
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                //alert("R: " + req + " S: " + status + " E: " + error);
                alert('Unable to connect server!');   
                return false;                 
            }
        }); 
       return flag;           
}
```

Comment: @AmitJoki note the `async: false` in the `$.ajax()` call ...

Comment: @Pointy it's no longer supported. It's been deprecated, unless OP is using a really old version of jQuery.

Comment: @AmitJoki I know it's been deprecated, but I *think* it still works in current browsers. Obviously if you're right about it not working then you're right about this being a duplicate :)

Comment: The docs (jQuery docs) say that it's deprecated but not that it doesn't work (except for cross-domain requests and JSONP of course). Also, obviously the OP *shouldn't* be doing a synchronous request because it's a terrible idea.

Comment: Yup. You're right. OP should clarify more.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to approach the problem.

Comment: hey guys so there is no solution for it.

Comment: Why don't you move your logic or whatever it has to run inside the success function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you not use DataType JSON?

```
function NextData() {           
    var lQIndex = $('#hfLastQIndex').val();  
    if (SaveData()) {
        alert('1111111');
        //Rest Code....
    }            
}

function SaveData(QNo) { 
    var flag = false;
    var res = $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { A : QNo },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.result);
            //alert("Test: " + data.result);
            if (data.result == "T")
                flag = true;                   
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            //alert("R: " + req + " S: " + status + " E: " + error);
            alert('Unable to connect server!');   
            return false;                 
        }
    }); 
    if(res){
        return flag;   
    }      
}
```

it's work for me..

Answer (score 2):

Using Callback functions, you can achieve this easily.

```
   function NextData() {           
            var lQIndex = $('#hfLastQIndex').val();  
            SaveData(lQIndex,function(result){
                   //rest code----
                   //result will be either true/false
            });
    }

    function SaveData(QNo, successCallback) {   
            var flag = false;
             $.ajax({
                url: '/Assessment/Save',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {A:QNo},
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert("Test: " + data.result);
                    if (data.result == "T")
                        flag = true;  
                      successCallback(flag);
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    //alert("R: " + req + " S: " + status + " E: " + error);
                    alert('Unable to connect server!'); 
                   flag = false;  
                    successCallback(flag);                 
                }
            }); 
           return flag;           
        }
```

http://gireeshsb.blogspot.in/2013/08/callback-functions-in-javascript.html
http://issacjk.blogspot.in/2014/08/callback-functions-in-javascript.html